# primary dark color android under API 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

i want to color the Statusbar, for a better look in Android 5.0. I want to set the three color primarydark,light and accent.

But my minimum API is 15. Is there any chance just to use this just under API lvl 21? Or do I have to create a seperate app with min. sdk 21?

EDIT:
Now i get everything i needed but the statisbar color won't change.

This is my values-v21/styles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
            <!-- API 21 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

And this the normal style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any Ideas why this won't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have different styles for different API levels.

For API < 21, you would use a normal `res/values/styles.xml`, and then for API 21+, you would have `res/values-v21/styles.xml`.

If the device is running API 21 or higher, then it will use the file in the `-v21` folder. If you just want to set `<color>` values, then just name the keys the same and do the same with `colors.xml`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Example:

`res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<!-- Colours for API <21 -->
<color name="primaryDark">#800000</color>
<color name="light">#800080</color>
<color name="accent">#FF0000</color>
```

`res/values-v21/colors.xml`:

```
<!-- Colours for API 21+ -->
<color name="primaryDark">#000008</color>
<color name="light">#080008</color>
<color name="accent">#0000FF</color>
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Added my XML Files. It doesn't work for me. Still have the black status bar.

Comment: Did you specify different `colors.xml` files as well?

Comment: Just created Thema. Where can I specify them?

Comment: You would use them in your styles.xml file, as you have in your question. Make sure they're named the same since my example and your question have different naming.

Comment: OP is trying to change status bar color. Pre-Lollipop the status bar color is not adjustable. While the solution you propose will change the values associated with those resources, they won't be used to style status bar pre-Lollipop.

Answer (score 2):

try set background programatically:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background));


actionbar_background.xml

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#e59300" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fbb903" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `colorPrimaryDark` is used to color the status bar...Status bar theme is a feature that was added to Android in Lollipop. **Keep in mind that the status bar will be black on older devices (no matter what the theme specifies).**

Referenced from 《Android Programming Guide 2ed》the big nerd ranch guide P360.
But I cannot find it in android developer guide.