# Making a new mortgage calculator project and think I have an API issue

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this error message

```
C:\Users\Student\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: 
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

It is making it so that my graphic display in eclispe is not working properly I am using API 19 and think I need to use API 21 am I even close?

Comment: check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444391/primary-dark-color-android-under-api-21

Answer (score 0):

```
sdk.buildtools=21.1.1
```

write this line in your **project.properties** file (if 21.1.1 is your latest build tools).

This error occurs because you are using older version of android build tools. So change it to the latest version of android build tools you have installed.

Comment: Thank you that was the start of a solution that worked