# AppCompatButton backgroundTint API < 21

Tags: android, android-button, android-appcompat, rippledrawable

I want to use ripple effects on Buttons. AppCompat v22.1 added AppCompatButton and new functionalities to AppCompat tinting.

My Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/add_remove_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Remove" />
```

On my API 22 test device the ripple effect works perfectly, but i'm coding for API 11 and unfortunately backgroundTint needs API >= 21. How can i set the ripple effect to Buttons on older API versions?

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26444391/primary-dark-color-android-under-api-21 you can your answer here.

Comment: Ripples don't work out of the box on pre-Lollipop, so you'll have to emulate them.

Comment: Ripple works only for api>=21

Comment: But according to http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html: "The full list of tint aware widgets at this time is: [...] AppCompatButton [...]"

Comment: Coloring a button works for me by applying a theme to the button having `colorButtonNormal` property (I tried 4.4.4 and 5.1).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Just use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`, the tint will take effect below Lollipop. The reason is `AppCompatActivity` `AppCompatDelegateImplV7` use `AppCompatViewInflater` to auto change Button or TextView to AppCompatButton or AppCompatTextView, then `app:backgroundTint` take effect.

[image]

Comment: And "app" is defined like this:  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: I have a linear layout on which i am using android:background="@drawable/background_sign_up" 
    app:backgroundTint="#dd282d50"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply", what to do.

Comment: Works but it says: "Unexpected namespace prefix “app” found for tag Button in app:backgroundTint line

Comment: For someone who get the error Unexpected namespace prefix “app” found for..., you might need to change Button to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

Comment: The AppCompatActivity changes the Buttons to AppCompatButton automatically, so you can ignore the warning

Comment: programmatically on KitKat?

Answer (score 2):

Ripples are not available as a build in functionality on Android <21. This is due to performance issues: devices with the new API can use the RenderThread which is not available to older devices. 
See also: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

> Why are there no ripples on pre-Lollipop?
>   A lot of what allows RippleDrawable to run smoothly is Android 5.0’s new RenderThread. To optimize for performance on previous versions of Android, we've left RippleDrawable out for now.

Answer (score 1):

To support ripple functionality below API 21 you may have to add a drawable in the background of your button:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/add_remove_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_ripple"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Remove" />
```

Then you have to add your xmls with the same name in both drawable and drawable-v21 directories (if you don't have them you may create and they will be automatically linked).

/res/drawable-v21/button_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/white">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

/res/drawable/button_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing as my use case: it was with **ImageView**:

`app:backgroundTint` was not taking effect because I used **`android:src`** tag for the background image in that Imageview.

when I changed it to `android:background` for Imageview then `app:backgroundTint` worked perfectly.

2nd Use case as mentioned by different answers one should use

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
```

instead of `ImageView`.