# what to use for backgroungTint in api level less than 21?

Tags: android, button

> Is there something instead of backgroundTint for api level less than 21?<

Answer (score 0):

Just use app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint, the tint will take effect below Lollipop. The reason is AppCompatActivity AppCompatDelegateImplV7 use AppCompatViewInflater to auto change Button or TextView to AppCompatButton or AppCompatTextView, then app:backgroundTint take effect.

[AppCompatButton backgroundTint API < 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890654/appcompatbutton-backgroundtint-api-21)

Comment: will this support for API > 21

Comment: Yes.. it should.. try it out.

Comment: what changes i have to make in other files or same files to use it?

Comment: just change **android:backgroundTint** to **app:backgroundTint** in your layout xml

Comment: It does not work . It say unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag Button

Comment: **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**        Add the app name space at top of XML...

Comment: Thanks, It's working :)

Comment: You can mark this as answer, as it is working for you.