# Why backgroundTint requires android: prefix after API 21 but not before?

Tags: android, xml-namespaces, android-styles

Declaring a style, when I define an item `android:backgroundTint`, I get a warning that this is available as of API 21 onward, while my minimum API specified is lower (API 17). On the other hand, when I replace that with simply `backgroundTint`, the warning is gone. Does anyone know why is that?

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#0F0</item>
</style>
```

Aside, from that, if I use `android:backgroundTint` for a single component, for example a button, I get no warning or error, no matter what my project's minimum SDK is. This is somewhat puzzling.

Comment: Cause `backgroundTint` introduced in API21 . Read [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTint). So this Style belongs to style v-21 . And for warning i think this is happening because `backgroundTint` individually not an attribute so not getting compiled .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why it works at runtime: AppCompat support library backports many of the later API level functionality and its styles define the [prefix-free `backgroundTint` attribute](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml#553).

Additional reason why lint does not complain: **style** attributes not prefixed with `android:` are not validated for known attribute names. You can actually put any string in `item` `name` attribute. For example:

```
<item name="iJustInventedThis">foo</item>
```

In layout widgets you get lint complaining about missing prefixes or unknown attributes. If you have an AppCompat widget such as `AppCompatImageView`, then you can use the `backgroundTint` attribute.

Comment: So, you can use any value for name in styles, but not for individual elements like Button, EditText, etc. As they need prefixes. Right?

Comment: In layout widgets you get lint complaining about missing prefixes or unknown attributes.

Comment: Might seem late, but your first paragraph raises my question. "... and its styles define the prefix-free backgroundTint attribute". Is that what you meant? I have a little problem understanding it.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question, but if you follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38355518/6398434) that instructs us to change `android:backgroundTint` to `app:backgroundTint`, you get rid of the following warning:

> Attribute backgroundTint is only used in API level 21 and higher

Comment: Thanks for that! It indeed works with AppCompat activities or AppCompat views :)

Comment: Great to know it helped you, @xarlymg89! As it helped a lot while I was a looking for a similar question, I thought it could help others and it's good to know it was really useful for another developer.