# Material Design Extended Floating Action Button has no ripple effect

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, ripple-effect

I am creating an Android app and I wanted to use extended floating action button so I added this code to my activity:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_game_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="@string/main_new_game"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_24px"/>
```

The button looks exactly how it is supposed to, except that it does not have ripple effect on click.

How can I add the ripple effect? I took the code straight from https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/#extended-fabs and it looks like the ripple should be there by default, but it does not work in my app. I have tried to create new project where I only set up the Material Components (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) and the button still does not have ripple effect. So it does not seem to be a problem with my project setup.

I have also tried setting the `app:rippleColor` attribute, setting `android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"` to no avail. Only thing that sort of worked was setting `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but the ripple effect was masked to rectangle instead of the shape of the extended FAB. Also setting the foreground is not very good approach since it is only supported on API 23 and higher and I am targeting API 21.

Comment: Make sure, your app uses the right theme.

Comment: @Ridcully my AppTheme extends Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use this attribute `app:rippleColor`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_game_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="@string/main_new_game"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_24px"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: I could swear I have tried this before and it did not work and now when I tried it it worked... oh well, thank you.

Comment: does not work when using custom background for it

Answer (score 1):

The default style of the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` has a **default**  `rippleColor` selector based on the **`colorOnSecondary`**.
Check in your app theme this color.

In any case you can override the color using:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        app:rippleColor="@color/my_selector" />
```

Or you can override the `colorOnSecondary` in your `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` using:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:theme="style/ExFabOverlay" />
```

with:

```
<style name="ExFabOverlay">
  <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Final note: use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. What is the difference between `app:backgroundTint` and `android:backgroundTint`?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890654/appcompatbutton-backgroundtint-api-21/38355518#38355518

Comment: @MartinOmacht backward compatibility